# Dealing with infinite loop (for a data stream) in kivy framework

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to create a gauge (like car Speedometer) that takes a continuous flow of data and uses that input to show gauge value on the screen. but the problem is that It's impossible to use infinite loops in kivy (it freezes). How can I deal with such thing? 
btw data will be received by an external device or software and the only problem is reading the data.

I've searched the internet but I haven't been much successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. You might want to use Kivy [Clock](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html) object and one of its function e.g. [`schedule_interval()`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html#kivy.clock.CyClockBase.schedule_interval) or [`create_trigger()`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html#kivy.clock.CyClockBase.create_trigger) in replacement of the infinite loops.

## Example

### Infinite loop

```
while True:
    read_data()
    time.sleep(.10)
```

### Using Kivy Clock » schedule_interval()

```
Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.read_data(), 0.10)
```